# How can I prevent the code from stopping and what is the problem? (updated)

Tags: c++, c++11, math, equation

I'm trying to translate this series into a code that give me the sum of it. Here is the series:
X + (-1/3)X^3  + (1/5)X^5 + (-1/7)X^7 + …. +((-1)^(n-1)/2n-1)X^(2n-1)

That's the code (by the way I can't use cmath library..):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "enter 2 numbers: \n";
    int x, n;
    cin >> x;
    do
    {
        cin >> n;
        if (n <= 0) cout << "ERROR \n";
    } while (n <= 0);

    int i{ 1 };                                     // index for the first organ and so on.
    double denom{ 2.0 * i - 1 };                    // the denominator and the power in the equation.

    bool posCardinal{ 1 };                          // check if the cardinal is positive.
    int cardinal{ 1 };
    if (posCardinal) cardinal = 1;
    else cardinal = -1;

    double factor{ cardinal / denom };              // the factor.
    int xValue{ x };                                // the value of X each time.
    double an{ factor * xValue };                   // general organ.
    double sum{ 0 };                                // the total sum.

    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        factor = cardinal / denom;
        for (int j{ 1 }; j < denom && i != 1; ++j)
        {
            xValue *= x;
        }
        an = factor * xValue;
        sum += an;
        xValue = x;
        !posCardinal;
    }
    cout << sum;
}
```

Why doesn't the code show me the sum?
Thank you all very much!!

Comment: 1st, I think you should use `double` than `int`. and... two `for ` loop has no `++i`... it is endless loop

Comment: `for (; i <= denom;)` what did you expect this to do?

Comment: What does it show you? Actual input and output, alongside expected output is valuable for [debugging](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with fractions in the series, you should think about using `float` or `double` (depending on what precision do you need) for your `x`, `xValue`, `sum`, `an` and `factor` (as its value is `1/some_int`, so if `factor` is `int`, then the value will almost always be `0`).

Your second problem are both `for` nested loops, which do not have any incrementer, so they work endlessly, similarly to `while (true){...}` loop - almost always `i` is smaller than `denom` (only if `i=1` the value of `denom` is `1`). You should think about rebuilding these functions to work on some other variable, let's say `j`. Then you could count n-th power of x this way:

```
for (int j = 0; j < denom; j++)
    xValue *= xValue;
```

There are still few things you should fix, e.g your `denom` does not change its value when the program is running, it has fixed value after you first declare it after `i`.